# Jquery: How to check if input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am building a mobile web app where the page is set to responsive through screen width and height. I am facing one issue here. In a mobile, if I click any input field, the screen size changes due to mobile keypad in some browsers. In this case I don't want the screen to resize. Where as the screen has to resize when we rotate screen. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Below is the part of code I am using for that.

```
function pageresponsive() {
    $('body').css('width', window.screen.width);
    $('body').css('height', window.screen.height);
}

pageresponsive();
var input_click_status = 0;
$("input").click(function() {
    input_click_status = 1;
});

$( "input" ).focus(function() {
    input_click_status = 1;
});

//This might not work as resize event will be set at the time of page load
if(input_click_status == 0) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        pageresponsive(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: use the on focus event  $(".myinput :input:visible:enabled:first").on('focus', function ()

Comment: @Tasos your method works for setting input_click flag. But it does not disable resize event.

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution

```
var isFocused =  $("input").is(":focus")
```

Answer (score 3):

for version 1.6+ of jquery

```
$("selector").is(":focus")
```

## [:Focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

you can check by two way:

you can bind an event on input.

```
var is_focused = false;
jQuery('input').bind('focus', function(){
  is_focused = true;
  /* you can write code what ever you want to do on focus.*/
});
```

or

there is one more function:

```
var is_focused = jQuery("input").is(":focus")
```